# I need some guidance on the substring function in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this particular code. Could someone please lend me some guidance to this?

Here is my question as well as what I have attempted to have as an outcome.

Modify songVerse to play "The Name Game" (OxfordDictionaries.com), by replacing "(Name)" with userName but without the first letter.

Ex: If userName = "Katie" and songVerse = "Banana-fana fo-f(Name)!", the program prints: 
Banana-fana fo-fatie!
Ex: If userName = "Katie" and songVerse = "Fee fi mo-m(Name)", the program prints: 
Fee fi mo-matie
Note: You may assume songVerse will always contain the substring "(Name)".

Code that I tried this last time...and no matter what I put in I keep getting the same results. I've tried different scenarios of the "userName.substring()" and still have the same outcome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameSong {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;
        String songVerse;

        userName = scnr.nextLine();
        userName = userName.substring(1); // Remove first character

        songVerse = scnr.nextLine();

        // Modify songVerse to replace (Name) with userName without first character

        songVerse = songVerse + userName.substring(1 , userName.length()); // this is where my problem is.

        System.out.println(songVerse);
    }
}
```

> 1 test passed
>
> All tests passed

```
Run
Testing Katie and Banana-fana fo-f(Name)!
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
Banana-fana fo-f(Name)!tie
Expected output
Banana-fana fo-fatie!
Testing Walter and Banana-fana fo-f(Name)!
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
Banana-fana fo-f(Name)!lter
Expected output
Banana-fana fo-falter!
Testing Katie and Fee fi mo-m(Name)
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
Fee fi mo-m(Name)tie
Expected output
Fee fi mo-matie
```

Comment: All your code is doing is adding `userName` minus the first two characters (You are using `substring(1)` twice) to the end of `songVerse`. You need to find the index of `Name` and then use `substring()` to insert the user name

Comment: I understand....thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

```
  userName = scnr.nextLine();
  userName = userName.substring(1); // Remove first character

  songVerse = scnr.nextLine();

  // Modify songVerse to replace (Name) with userName without first character

    songVerse = songVerse.replace("(Name)", userName.substring(0));

  System.out.println(songVerse);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

here you removed first character already from userName, so at the second last line you again don't need to remove it.
and for the song Verse, you need to remove "(NAME)" from it, so here you can use

```
songVerse = songVerse.replace("(NAME)","");
songVerse = songVerse+userName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method substring(int begin, int end) let hoose/create a substring from the initial String indicating the numbers of chars from which the substring should begin and end or begin only. There are no other variants to edit a substring, while it will not become a part of a freshly made string (“String songVerse” in your case). The object.replace() method should change the indicated “Text” (in your case it’s a “(Name)”) onto anything that you’d like to be inserted instead of it independently on the quantity or type of the chars before or after the “Text”. The variant proposed by Nicholas K is correct and should work or you can try its shorter version, however the result will be the same:

```
public class NameSong  {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;
        String songVerse;

        userName = scnr.nextLine();
        songVerse = scnr.nextLine();
        songVerse = songVerse.replace("(Name)", userName.substring(1));

      System.out.println(songVerse);
   }

}
```

Comment: Okay....thank you all for your time and guidance. I did get the understanding of the substring() method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not attempting to solve the problem that you described in your question.

Try following these steps:

1. Devise a list of steps written in English to solve the problem; pay attention to details.
2. Run the list of steps in step 1 by hand.
3. Convert the steps in step 1 to code.

Here are some hints:

- You will be reading the lyrics one line at a time.
- Some lines have a replacement and others do not.
- You will receive the Name as input one time; generate the name replacement value one time and use it each time you perform a replacement.

Your code is terrible.
Here is some more about "Pay attention to details"

- You do not have a loop in your code;
  this will read one line of lyrics and perform one substitution.
  Count the number of lines in the lyrics.
  If the number of lines is greater than one,
  then your technique is guaranteed to fail.
- If you have a loop in your code but decided not to include it in your code,
  stop lying in your questions.
  We can not help you fix code that you pretend does not exist.
- In a sane world,
  the name to use for the substitutions will appear exactly one time.
  Read it one time.
- In order to replace (Name) in a string, you must first find (Name) in a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameSong {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userName;
  String songVerse;

  userName = scnr.nextLine();
  userName = userName.substring(1); // Remove first character

  songVerse = scnr.nextLine();

  // Modify songVerse to replace (Name) with userName without first character
   songVerse = songVerse.replace("(Name)", userName);
  /* Your solution goes here  */

  System.out.println(songVerse);
  }
}
```